# locking call to webservice in ASP.NET to avoid Oracle CRM time per web service call limit

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a web application using ASP.NET, that is connecting to Oracle CRM as a back end. The ASP.Net uses some business objects to call into the Oracle CRM webservices, and this works fine.

Except, however, Oracle CRM has a limitation where they only allow you to make 20 web service calls per second (or one call per 50mS), and if you exceed this rate a SOAPException is returned "**The maximum rate of requests was exceeded. Please try again in X ms.**"

The traffic to the site has increased recently, so we are now getting a lot of these SOAPExceptions, but as the code that calls the webservice is wrapped up in a business object, I thought I would modify it to ensure that the 50ms limit is never breached.

I use the following code

```
private static object lock_obj = new object();
lock (lock_obj)
{
    call webservice;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

However, I am still getting some SOAP Exceptions. I did try writing the code using mutexes instead of lock(), but the performance impact proved to be a problem.

Can anyone explain to me why my solution isn't workinf, and perhaps suggest an alternative?

Comment: Perhaps you are solving the wrong problem. Why dont you find alternatives to the Oracle CRM, which is causing this problem in the first place. Whatever may be your solution, the additional traffic is going to bring down your system anyway, may be little later.

Comment: Brillian ideat, and exactly what needs to be done, but not under my control unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Moved to answer. Possible due to > 1 IIS worker process. I don't think object locking spans worker processes so subsequent simultaneous threads could be started but I could be wrong

http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Log4net-Thread-Safe-but-not-Process-Safe

My suggestion would be an application variable which stores the tick of the last request, then from that you can work out when it's safe to fire the next.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, but the app pool in question is set to one worker process

Comment: What type of data is going in and out, could you not cache against the incoming data to reduce oracle calls? There must be a better way than slowing down the WS calls

Comment: Yes, caching is an option, but requires a more significant rewrite of the application

Answer (score 1):

As long as your application is running with only one ASP.NET worker process you should be ok with what you have, but there are a few things to potentially consider.

1. Are you using a Web Garden?  If so this creates multiple worker processes and therefore a lock is only obtained per/process
2. Are you in a load balanced environment?  If so you will need to go to a different method.

Comment: Not using a web garden, and not using loadbalancing, so I think there should only be one worker process being used. That's why I'm puzzled that I'm still getting the SoapExceptions

Comment: it could be a timing precision issue.  Try bumping your sleep up to 100 and see if they go away.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out that a compounding issue was that we have a windows service running on the same server that was also calling into some of the same objects every 4 minutes (running on a different process of course). When I turn it off (and having bumped the sleep up to 100 as per Mitchel's suggestion) the problem seems to have gone away **almost** entirely.

I say almost, because every so often I still get the odd mysterious soapexception, but I think by and large the problem is sorted. I'm still a bit mystified as to how we can get any of these Exceptions, but we will live with it for now.

I think Oracle should publicise this *feature* of Oracle CRM on Demand a little more widely.